# why the background property is not running?

Tags: css

There are my codes. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vE8rd/))
Why this part of my codes isn't running?

```
header{background-color: #2bd5ec;}
```

I want to add background color to header tag. What i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `overflow:hidden`

```
header{background-color: #2bd5ec; overflow:hidden;}
```

> The [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow) CSS property specifies whether to clip content, render scroll bars or display overflow content of a block-level element.
>
> Using the [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow) property with a value different than `visible`, its default, will create a new block formatting context. This is technically necessary as if a float would intersect with the scrolling element it would force to rewrap the content of the scrollable element around intruding floats. The rewrap would happen after each scroll step and would be lead to a far too slow scrolling experience. Note that, by programmatically setting scrollTop to the relevant HTML element, even when overflow has the hidden value an element may need to scroll.
>
> The [overflow](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html) declaration tells the browser what to do with content that doesn't fit in a box. This assumes the box has a height: if it doesn't, it becomes as high as necessary to contain its contents, and the overflow declaration is useless.

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/vE8rd/13/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that since the elements inside your `header` are floated, they're considered in a different flow than your header, and thus it doesn't resize to fit them.

One way to fix this is to append `<div style = "clear: both;"></div>` to your `header`; little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/vE8rd/7/).

You can also just add `overflow: hidden;` to your `header`: [another little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/vE8rd/14/), or `float` it as well: [yet another little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/vE8rd/15/).

Comment: no need to append `<div style = "clear: both;"></div>` you can use `overflow:hidden`

Comment: we can use clear:both but its older solution the new solution is overflow:hidden; and this will also reduce our markup as well as.......

Comment: @ShailenderArora @A.K `overflow: hidden` works as well, but it'd prevent you from having scrollbars in the case of having some actual overflow. I didn't say that any of the methods above is best; they all work, but it depends on your personal preference.

Comment: @Abody97 actually we use overflow:hidden; for mac users...If Explorer Mac is still important to you, use overflow: hidden. This browser always shows scrollbars when you use overflow: auto; and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

you can set Height for Header.
for example :

```
header{background-color: red; height:100px;}
```

and you can use "clear" like this :

```
 <header>
     <div id="info">
         <h1>Oyunn.in</h1>
     </div>
     <div id="categories">
         <p>Barbie - Benten - Senten</p>
     </div>
     <br clear="all"/>
</header>​
```

and css:

```css
header{background-color: #2bd5ec;}
#info{float: left;}
#info h1{font-size: 100%;margin: 0;}
#categories{float: right;}
#categories p{margin:0;}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
header{background-color: #2bd5ec;width:100%; height:30px;}
```

Background attribute usually needs div's dimensions

Comment: Nope, this isn't about dimensions. This is because the elements inside the `header` are all floated.

Answer (score 0):

actually you didn't clear your child floats so whenever we are using float so we should clear the floats and we can give `overflow: hidden;` in our parent div to clearing the child floated div's.

```
header {
    background-color: #2BD5EC;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**see the demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/vE8rd/17/

Comment: thanks for beautiful answer. meantime, how can i remove white spaces(top,left,right)? http://tinypic.com/r/r1a4ua/6